# Unmount unnecessary drives

Tags: linux, mount, umount

My disk position looks like this:

```
# df -HP
Filesystem             Size   Used  Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2              256G   177G    67G  73% /
/dev/sda1              510M    18M   467M   4% /boot
tmpfs                  8.5G      0   8.5G   0% /dev/shm
//10.10.10.10/softwares/shared_by_shantanu/abc/   2.0T   865G   1.2T  44% /mnt/windowsabc
//10.10.10.10/softwares/shared_by_shantanu/abc/   2.0T   865G   1.2T  44% /windosabc1
//10.10.10.10/abc/     2.0T   865G   1.2T  44% /mnt/windowsabc1
```

I would like to know how to unmount the "shared_by_shantanu" setting since that is obsolete now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is [**`umount`**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/umount).

```
umount /mnt/windowsabc
umount /windosabc1
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply use the `umount` command followed by the path where each share is mounted:

```
umount /mnt/windowsabc
umount /windosabc1
umount /mnt/windowsabc1
```

Then remove the relevant entries from `/etc/fstab` to avoid them being mounted again at system boot.

Comment: Note that only the superuser can use umount in most cases (depending on fstab entries). You may need to use sudo or su.